# Middleware not redirect

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, middleware

I'm writing a simple system to control authentication for users, only registered users have access to the site. If you are not authenticated redirect you to the login page.

Quite simply I'm using a middleware to make this control.

My problem is that when the condition for the redirection is valid, this does not happen!

```
// Routes
module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);

    if (typeof(res.session) == 'undefined' && req.url != '/users/login') {
        console.log('redirect');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    } else {
        console.log('no redirect');
        next();
    }
});

app.get('/',                    routes.site.index);

app.all('/users/login',         routes.user.login);
};
```

Obviously, the stout console is:

```
/
redirect
/users/login
no redirect
```

And the page is loading indefinitely...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

PS: I apologize if I misspelled, Google helped me!

@-------------------- EDIT:

I opted to use Passport for the management of Auth.

I only have one problem, I run the routes of my app in a separate file.

***app.js***

```
// Auth
var passport = require('passport'), strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new strategy(function(username, password, done) {
var user = require('./db')('user');

user.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false);
    if (!user.validPassword(password)) return done(null, false);

    return done(null, user);
});
}));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
var user = require('./db')('user');

user.findOne(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});
// End Auth

require('./routes')(app, passport);

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

***routes/index.js***

```
// Routes
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    app.get('/', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }), routes.site.index);

    app.all('/login', routes.user.login);
};
```

***routes/user.js***

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    switch (req.method) {
        default:
        case 'GET':
            res.render('user/login', {title: 'Login'});
        break;
        case 'POST':
            /*passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
                res.json([user, info]);
            });
            */
        break;
    }
};
```

The redirect to the login page works fine, but I would manage the routes in different files, and so I can not help maintain the variable **passport** to be able to handle the callback control in the file user.js.

Ideas?
Thanks!!!

Comment: what does `routes.user.login` look like?

Comment: Undefined in that case is not a string, just remove the quotes around it. It's a reserved word, kind of like null.

Comment: @RyanLaBarre that was my original answer, but I modified it because I noticed he was using typeof() which does return a string. You could not use typeof() and you could evaluate it with the ketyword `undefined`, right?

Comment: I highly recommend you use an authentication module. I recommend Jared Hanson's Passport.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Connect's session middleware, most likely every request will have a session associated with it.  You'll need to check if there's a user ID (or similar) set in the session to make the authenticated/unauthenticated determination.

I'm also the developer of [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), which works alongside [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login) middleware to protect access to authenticated routes.  I'd recommend looking at that, as it will allow you to get an authentication system up and running quickly.

Comment: Right, I think the original poster is confusing a session with a successful login now that I looked twice at it. I thought at first that he wasn't using typedef()

Comment: Just figured this out. Passport website actually doesn't specifically mention using "connect-ensure-login". I looked at this gist https://gist.github.com/jaredhanson/3989193 and realised I needed that.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this instead:

`if (user.loggedin === undefined && req.url != '/users/login')`

I'm pretty sure Express gives a session for each requester; logged in or not. So, you need a check on login not on session.

Comment: Actually, I'm not to sure about my answer to your question. Comment here and let me know if this is helpful or not. I think every client that accesses your site gets a session, it's just that you want to evaluate whether they are logged in.